# Implementing Vehicle Routing Problem in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, network-analyst

I am trying to solve the "Vehicle Routing Problem", using ModelBuilder.

For example, using [Exercise 7: Servicing a set of orders with a fleet of vehicles](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/na/004700000062000000/) from the Network Analyst Tutorial:

1. add a "Make Vehicle Routing Problem Layer" tool
2. add a "Add Locations" tool and set "stores" as "input location"
3. add a"Add Locations" tool and set "Distribution Center" as "input location"
4. add a "solve"tool to calculate.

That's all ... and I have a error "Routes class is empty."

I think I have to add that something connected with the route class, but I did not understand how to do it in ModelBuilder

[image]

[Click here for higher resolution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIEWd.png)

How to make the scheme correctly?

PS Sorry for my english

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include the precise steps that you did and where you are stuck rather then requiring potential answerers to read the tutorial, please?  I suspect that by doing this there is a chance that you will discover where you may have gone astray and if not we will know precisely what you did.

Comment: 1) add a "Make Vehicle Routing Problem Layer" tool
2) add a "Add Locations" tool and set "stores" as "input location"
3) add a"Add Locations" tool and set "Distribution Center" as "input location"
4) add a "solve"tool to calculate.

That's all ...

I think I have to add that something connected with the route class, but I did not understand how to do it in modelbuilder

Comment: There is an edit button beneath your question that will enable you to improve it with content of your above comment.  Potential answerers do not always look at the comments and having a revised and hopefully improved question body may entice them to stop and help rather than move on to read the next question.

Comment: I cannot test this because I do not currently have access to a Network Analyst license but in your next edit would you be able to make clear whether you are using the same data as in that tutorial and whether in essence your question is "How to automate Network Analyst Tutorial Ex. 7 using ModelBuilder?", please?